# Ensure numeric display always has 2 decimal places

Tags: excel, vba, decimal

Good Day,

I have price and spread values.
Price is numeric, while Spread can be +1, +0.5, -0.5, -1 or "Flat" aka 0

My task is to put the 2 values together.

E.g.
Price = 600

[image]

I need the final result to always show 2 decimal places, even if they are .00

And it cannot round up or down.
But my .00 are always trimmed off.

What I always get:
[image]

Any advise is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It looks like you have tried something at least, why not show it to everyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a formula:

Assuming that the price is stored in a named range `Price` and your data is stored in column A, starting in row 2:

```
=TEXT(B2,"0.00")&" ("&IF(B2-PRICE=0,"Flat",ROUND(B2-PRICE,2))&")"
```

**Explanation:**

The `TEXT`-function converts a number into a formatted string, giving a format pattern. '0.00' will format the value with 2 decimals - that gives you for example `600.00` or `599.95`

```
TEXT(B2,"0.00")
```

Now we use the `IF`-function to check if the value is equal to `PRICE` or different. If it is equal to `PRICE`, we write the string `Flat`, else we calculate the difference. We need to use the `ROUND`-function because else we can get a difference of `0.00999999` instead of `0.01` because of floating point math.

```
IF(B2-PRICE=0,"Flat",ROUND(B2-PRICE,2)
```

The rest is string concatenation

Comment: Thank you. Since I am using VBA, I modify to WorksheetFunction.Text(price, "0.00") & " (" & spread & ")"